# Best way to track Windows Service Unhandled Exception

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a Windows Service application. The service is basically copying Excel files to a directory at specific hours, then reading Excel rows and finally updating SQL Server tables according to the data in the row it reads.

Recently, it crashes sometimes. While I was reviewing logs, I found it crashed because:

> Application: WinCCServiceIzmit.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319
> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>
> Exception Info: System.IO.IOException
>
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32, System.String)
> at System.IO.FileStream.Init(System.String, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess, Int32, Boolean, System.IO.FileShare, Int32, System.IO.FileOptions, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
> at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(System.String, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess, System.IO.FileShare, Int32, System.IO.FileOptions, System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
> at System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(System.String, Boolean, Boolean)
> at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(System.String, Boolean, System.Text.Encoding, Int32, Boolean)
> at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(System.String, Boolean)
> at System.IO.File.AppendText(System.String)
> at WinccService.InnerOperation.WriteToFile(System.String)
> at WinccService.InnerOperation.Stop()
> at WinccService.WinccIzmit.start()
> at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
> at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Do you guys have any idea how can I track where the problem comes from? Application has too many code rows.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either subscribe to [UnhandeledException Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.unhandledexception) or wrap on the highest level within your service (maybe within your method you start in `OnStart`) into a try-catch.

By this way you can catch the exception and write more details into a separate log file to find out what happens.

Nevertheless, inspecting your stack it seems the error occurs in `WinccService.InnerOperation.WriteToFile()` which will be called from `WinccService.InnerOperation.Stop()`. So looking into these two methods and who calls them should help you track down the issue. Additionally it seems that at this point a `System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile()` will be called and fails. Possible causes could be an invalid file name, the file already exists or a permission problem.